# Print part of a JSP page successful, but DIV section getting split

Tags: javascript, jsp

I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/503415/Print-Div-Content-Using-JavaScript) site that gave me exactly what I need, however I'm trying to get any DIV section to not get split up during printing.  My page has about 5 DIV elements within the one DIV that I'm retrieving.  Each DIV within the main one can be X amount of length and can have multiple ones within it (see code block with 'class="SomeHistory"'), so it could be any of them that gets split up while printing.

It isn't creating a new page, so it should contain all the Style within it, so I'm not for sure of what can be done or not.

NOTE: further below is the actual

```
<div id="divToPrint" >
<div class="detail">
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:600;">
  ..
  ..
 </table>
</div>

<div class="detail">
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:600;">
  ..
  ..
 </table>
</div>

<div class="detail" style="page-break-after: auto">
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:600;">
  ..
  ..
 </table>
</div>

<c:forEach items="${simpleList}" var="rez">
<jsp:useBean scope="request" id="rez" class="SomeHistory"/> 

<div class="detail" style="page-break-after: avoid">
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:600;">
  ..
  ..
 </table>
</div>
</c:forEach>

<div class="detail" style="page-break-after: auto">
&nbsp;
</div> 

<div class="detail" style="page-break-after: auto">
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:600;">
  ..
 </table>
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:600;">
  ..
  ..
</div>
</div>
```

This is the actual javascript used from the link, nothing changed but the "getElementById"..

```
function printDiv(divID) {
//Get the HTML of div
var divElements = document.getElementById("divToPrint").innerHTML;
//Get the HTML of whole page
var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

//Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
document.body.innerHTML = 
  "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
  divElements + "</body>";
//Print Page
window.print();

//Restore orignal HTML
document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to change the following:

```
<c:forEach items="${simpleList}" var="rez">
<jsp:useBean scope="request" id="rez" class="SomeHistory"/> 

<div class="detail" style="page-break-inside: avoid">
```

I had to adjust some of the others of the page-break, but now works to keep the DIV sections together while printing.